# Fill list and dict with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

How to fill dict and list with ThreadPoolExecutor?
Function returns empty dict and list.
I cannot use multiprocessing for this task due to Windows issues.
Seems like Manager() doesn`t work the same way like in multiprocessing.
Here is my code:

```
def parser(link, data, exceptions, driver = driver):
    try:    
        data_ = {}
        driver.get(link)
        brand = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="middle"]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/h1').text
        name = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="section-st-block9"]/div[2]/div/div[1]').find_elements('tag name', 'div')
        field = name[0].text
        name_ = name[1].text
        data_[field] = name_
        contacts = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="section-st-block5"]/div[2]/div[1]').find_elements('class name', 'content-contact-item')
        for contact in contacts:
             fields = contact.find_elements('tag name', 'div')
             field = fields[0].text
             name__ = fields[1].text
             data_[field] = name__
        data[brand] = data_
    except:
        exceptions.append(link)

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
data = manager.dict()
exceptions = manager.list()
#collecting links from page...
for i in range(132, 142):
    core = 'https://fabricators.ru/zavody?region=19569&page={}'
    url = core.format(i)
    driver.get(url)
    companies = driver.find_elements('class name', 'content-list-item')
    links = []
    for c in companies:    
        x = c.find_element('tag name', 'a').get_attribute('href')
        links.append(x)
    #...and provide them as argument of function
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parser, links, data, exceptions): #also tried with itertools.repeat
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use heavyweight `selenium`, just get the data using `requests`/`beautifulsoup`. Here is an example how you can do it quickly using two `multiprocessing.Pool` (one for getting links, second for getting the data from the link):

```py
from itertools import chain
from multiprocessing import Pool

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://fabricators.ru/zavody?region=19569&page={}"


def get_links(page_num):
    u = base_url.format(page_num)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(u, cookies={"beget": "begetok"}).content, "html.parser"
    )

    out = []
    for a in soup.select("a.title-site--h3"):
        out.append("https://fabricators.ru" + a["href"])

    return out


def get_data_from_link(link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(link, cookies={"beget": "begetok"}).content, "html.parser"
    )
    title = soup.h1.text
    address = soup.h1.find_next("p").text

    # ... get other data here

    return title, address


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool1, Pool(processes=4) as pool2:
        links = pool1.imap_unordered(get_links, range(132, 134))
        for title, address in pool2.imap_unordered(
            get_data_from_link, chain.from_iterable(links)
        ):
            # print the data, or store it to the dictionary etc...

            print(title)
            print(address)
            print()
```

Prints:

```
...

Завод Энергокабель
Московская область, Ногинский р-н, Электроугли, ул. Полевая, 10

Завод Микропровод
Московская область, Подольск, ул. Бронницкая, 3

КабельЭлектроСвязь
Московская область, Ленинский р-н, Видное, территория Северная Промзона, ул. Проектируемый проезд №5208

Завод КвантКабель
Московская область, Дмитров, ул. Пушкинская, 1, стр.15

...
```

---

EDIT: `ThreadPool` version:

```py
from itertools import chain
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://fabricators.ru/zavody?region=19569&page={}"


def get_links(page_num):
    u = base_url.format(page_num)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(u, cookies={"beget": "begetok"}).content, "html.parser"
    )

    out = []
    for a in soup.select("a.title-site--h3"):
        out.append("https://fabricators.ru" + a["href"])

    return out


def get_data_from_link(link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(link, cookies={"beget": "begetok"}).content, "html.parser"
    )
    title = soup.h1.text
    address = soup.h1.find_next("p").text

    # ... get other data here

    return title, address


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPool(processes=2) as pool1, ThreadPool(processes=4) as pool2:
        links = pool1.imap_unordered(get_links, range(132, 134))
        for title, address in pool2.imap_unordered(
            get_data_from_link, chain.from_iterable(links)
        ):
            # print the data, or store it to the dictionary etc...

            print(title)
            print(address)
            print()
```

Comment: Hello Andrej, 
I'v tried first with requests, but 'get' method returns no html body....
I'll try your code with cookies, it can be solutions in my case. You are right, it`s much faster.
However, the most important issue is Pool.  It`s simply pending. This is common issue on Windows. That`s why I`v asked about ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @Vladislav You can use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` The only difference is it uses threads instead processes. The script I posted should be the same.

Comment: @Vladislav I've added `ThreadPool` version as well.

Comment: first of all, thank you! Requests.get now returns html. 
I'll review my code with BS and come back with answer

Comment: how to provide multiply args to ThreadPool.imap_unordered?
I'v tried:
1) zip(links, repeat(manager.dict()), repeat(manager.list())
2) ((links[i], {}, []) for i in range(10))
P.S. I have to collect exceptions and cannot proceed like you`ve proposed. Two scenario are possible.

Comment: @Vladislav Don't pass empty list and dicts to the functions (why?), you can use initarg that the Pool has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255605/discussion-between-vladislav-and-andrej-kesely).